# Assert MagicMock inside of callable parameter

Tags: python, unit-testing, lambda, callable

In order to prevent calls to external resources. For example via `requests.get` while running unit tests I want to have a function that looks like this:

```py
def call_external_resource(call: typing.Callable[[], Response]) -> http.Response:
    if settings.UNDER_TESTING and not isinstance(call,MagicMock) and not callable_contains_mock(call):
        raise Exception('attempted to call external resource while testing')
    return call()
```

I don't know how I can build the `callable_contains_mock`

Comment: If your code has a check if you are testing then there's a fair chance you are doing the tests wrongly.

Comment: I agree that this is a particularly bad smell on testing that there's a check whether the function is in testing. Do you have any suggestions on how to force the test to fail when a developer tries to reach for external resources in a unit test?

Comment: You will have to add more information to get useful hints on how to improve the tests.

Comment: I see my original question wasn't very clear. I'm trying to prevent developers from attempting to make http requests while running unit tests.